# pass array to chart.js option

Tags: php, arrays, chart.js

i have this array:

```
array (
  0 => 'rgba(202, 63, 20, 1)',
  1 => 'rgba(35, 14, 225, 1)',
  2 => 'rgba(73, 128, 13, 1)',
  3 => 'rgba(238, 62, 10, 1)',
  4 => 'rgba(85, 152, 95, 1)',
  5 => 'rgba(57, 156, 150, 1)',
)
```

but i have to use it as a parameter in a chart.js chart and i need this format:

```
['rgba(202, 63, 20, 1)', 'rgba(35, 14, 225, 1)', 'rgba(73, 128, 13, 1)']
```

and i have to do it in PHP.
some ideas ?
thanks
C.

Comment: Use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks. json_encode it comes close to the result I need but it still doesn't work.
json_encode gives me this:
["rgba (242, 145, 145, 1)", "rgba (208, 196, 61, 1)", "rgba (240, 84, 137, 1)", "rgba (107, 35, 236, 1 ) "," rgba (73, 158, 71, 1) "," rgba (213, 42, 230, 1) "]

but I need it like this:
['rgba (202, 63, 20, 1)', 'rgba (35, 14, 225, 1)', 'rgba (73, 128, 13, 1)']

with single quotes - '- and not double quotes - "-
do you know how to do it? Thanks so much!

Comment: No, I don't, because that's not any valid format I know of. If you need JSON (which JavaScript uses, it stands for "JavaScript Object Notation" after all), then it should be double quotes. Have you actually tried it, or are you just getting stuck on it not looking like some example you've seen? I know that Chart.js definitely accepts JSON.

Comment: of course I tried it !! but it does not work!
You're right, chart.js accepts that format (I tried to manually enter only 1 value written like this: "rgba (255, 99, 132, 1)" and it works, but when I pass the array created with json_encode it doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: Which function / option in chart.js are you trying to pass this data to? Are you certain it accepts arrays, and not just single values? Can we have a documentation link, please? Can we have a [mre] of your issue in the question please, not just some abstract snippets out of context. Show how you encode the data, and show how you pass it to chart.js, and tell us if you get any console errors or anything else like that. You can use your question's "edit" button to update it - don't post all that into these comments please.

Comment: We're glad you fixed it but...please do not mark questions as "resolved" by editing them. Instead, you must add an Answer below. That's how Stackoverflow works - it's a Question and Answer site. The answer is not part of the question! You are allowed to add an Answer onto your own question, then others can vote it up if they find it useful. Right now, to a search engine, your question appears to still be unanswered and will not show highly in results, so it's not so useful to everyone else. Please take the [tour] if you're unsure how Stackoverflow is structured. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted the edit from the question and answered by resolution. Sorry for my inexperience here.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it: I pass my rgba array to the `"backgroundColor"` option in Chart.js with this string:

```
backgroundColor: <?php echo json_encode($ColorArray); ?>,
```

and now it works.

My mistake was in passing the php variable directly to the backgroundColor option of chart.js like this:

```
backgroundColor: $ColorArray,
```